# Extract data from a ListPlot for specified x values in a regular way

Tags: data

I have 2 sets of data which I didn't produce by myself:

```
 data1={{0.716049, 0.054878}, {0.730247, 0.100271}, {0.746296, 
  0.145664}, {0.761111, 0.191734}, {0.775926, 0.238482}, {0.793827, 
  0.283198}, {0.816667, 0.325203}, {0.844444, 0.363144}, {0.887037, 
  0.349593}, {0.911728, 0.313008}, {0.926543, 0.26626}, {0.93642, 
  0.21748}, {0.945062, 0.168699}, {0.953086, 0.120596}, {0.959259, 
  0.0724932}, {0.96358, 0.0237127}, {0.972222, 0.0921409}, {0.974074, 
  0.140921}, {0.977778, 0.189702}, {0.981481, 0.237805}, {0.984568, 
  0.286585}, {0.987037, 0.335366}, {0.988889, 0.384146}, {0.988889, 
  0.432927}, {0.994444, 0.48103}, {1.00617, 0.47832}, {1.00679, 
  0.525745}, {1.02778, 0.566396}, {1.05556, 0.604336}, {1.06049, 
  0.619919}, {1.08704, 0.658537}, {1.11728, 0.694444}, {1.15802, 
  0.71477}, {1.20247, 0.71748}, {1.24198, 0.70122}, {1.27222, 
  0.668699}, {1.29444, 0.626694}, {1.31049, 0.579946}, {1.32222, 
  0.53252}, {1.33333, 0.485095}, {1.34444, 0.437669}, {1.35556, 
  0.390244}, {1.36667, 0.342818}, {1.37778, 0.29065}, {1.3784, 
  0.295393}, {1.39444, 0.25}, {1.40617, 0.253388}, {1.42222, 
  0.29878}, {1.43395, 0.346206}, {1.44383, 0.394986}, {1.45617, 
  0.442412}, {1.47469, 0.485095}, {1.50741, 0.613144}};
```

and

```
 data2={{0.76934, -0.00340832}, {0.812929, 0.00204499}, {0.851669, 
  0.0184049}, {0.881911, 0.0511247}, {0.903625, 0.0947512}, {0.919222,
   0.141786}, {0.931755, 0.189502}, {0.942448, 0.237219}, {0.950691, 
  0.285617}, {0.957093, 0.334015}, {0.962882, 0.382413}, {0.96867, 
  0.430811}, {0.973845, 0.479209}, {0.978407, 0.527607}, {0.978678, 
  0.576687}, {0.984471, 0.625767}, {0.98458, 0.645535}, {0.990368, 
  0.693933}, {0.996157, 0.742331}, {1.00387, 0.693933}, {1.00921, 
  0.662577}, {1.02615, 0.619632}, {1.06716, 0.601227}, {1.09949, 
  0.568507}, {1.11336, 0.524199}, {1.12536, 0.476483}, {1.13921, 
  0.428766}, {1.15307, 0.382413}, {1.16508, 0.335378}, {1.17586, 
  0.287662}, {1.18787, 0.240627}, {1.20295, 0.194274}, {1.23298, 
  0.188821}, {1.24734, 0.235174}, {1.25865, 0.28289}, {1.26934, 
  0.330607}, {1.28065, 0.378323}, {1.29196, 0.42604}, {1.30326, 
  0.473756}, {1.31518, 0.521472}, {1.32833, 0.568507}, {1.34269, 
  0.61486}, {1.36012, 0.65985}, {1.3806, 0.702795}, {1.40476, 
  0.744376}, {1.43502, 0.781186}, {1.46833, 0.813906}, {1.49552, 
  0.849352}};
```

We can `ListPlot` them:

```
 plotexp1 = 
 ListPlot[data1, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 4, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Red}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
  ImageSize -> 200 2, Axes -> None, FrameStyle -> Black]

  plotexp2 = 
     ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
      InterpolationOrder -> 4, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
      PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Red}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
      ImageSize -> 200 2, Axes -> None, FrameStyle -> Black]
```

It is possible to extract data from these 2 plots:

```
dataext1=Cases[plotexp1, Line[x__] -> x, \[Infinity]]

dataext2=Cases[plotexp1, Line[x__] -> x, \[Infinity]]
```

The data extracted from them are not managed in a regular way. Suppose I want to add the `y` values of these two sets of data for the same `x`, for example `x = 1`. But I don't have access to the values of `y` for this `x`. My question is how can I extract data from these `ListPlot`s for specified values of `x`, for example `x = 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data extracted from the plot is simply a resampling of the original data, and there is no reason to expect that any given `x` value will be part of the sample.  You need to use `Interpolation`, but first you have to decide how to deal with the multi-valued nature of your function.  You could delete points having the same `x` value (I think it's just one point in `data1`)

For example, you could use

```
func = Interpolation[dataext1 // First // DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]]
func[0.8]
(* 0.294543 *)
```

You can get a similar answer just by using your original data,

```
func = Interpolation[data1 // DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]];
func[0.8]
(* 0.295968 *)
```

where you can also use the `InterpolationOrder` option if you like.